# Entering values from one div to another

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have

```
<div id="arrayValues">6,10,4,19,7,11</div>

<div id="results">
  <div id="firstnumber">6</div>
  <div id="secondnumber">10</div>
  <div id="thirdnumber">4</div>
  <div id="fourthnumber">19</div>
  <div id="fifthnumber">7</div>
  <div id="sixtnumber">11</div>
</div>
<div id="resultScript"></div>
```

I need to put those values from arrayValues into resultScript div.

I have tried numerous of things, and I'm unsure why they don't work. One of things I've tried was

```
var val = document.getElementById("arrayValues");
var a = document.getElementById("resultScript");
  a.value = "val";
```

I've also tried, this one seems better try, but I seem to be missing something.

```
var values = document.getElementById("arrayValues").value
var results = document.getElementById("resultScript").innerHTML = "values";
```

Comment: Have you tried to loop over `results` ?

Comment: Can you add the exact output that you expect?

Comment: What/where is arrayValues ?

Comment: ye, i missed writing first line, it was <div id="arrayValues">6,10,4,19,7,11</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="arrayValues">6,10,4,19,7,11</div>
    <div id="results">
      <div id="firstnumber">6</div>
      <div id="secondnumber">10</div>
      <div id="thirdnumber">4</div>
      <div id="fourthnumber">19</div>
      <div id="fifthnumber">7</div>
      <div id="sixtnumber">11</div>
    </div>
    <div id="resultScript"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Get all the elements with the numbers and make an array out of it
var result = Array.from(document.getElementById('results').querySelectorAll('div'))
  .map(function (elt) { return elt.innerHTML }) // Get the numbers
  .join(',') // Useless if really using comma as separator, but you can change it later

document.getElementById('resultScript').innerHTML = result
```